# While executing disabled datepicker script by javascript, getting error. How to resolve?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**Error:**

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: document.getElementById(...) is null
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:32:46'
```

**Code:**

```
package TestngPackage;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class datepicker {

    public static void main (String[] args){


        System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", "E:\\selenium-2.53.1\\geckodriver.exe");
        FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://192.163.222.186/~puzzlelife/development/#/register");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  
         JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
         js.executeScript("document.getElementById('bdate').value='02/03/2015'");

    }
}
```

Comment: it would be helpful to see the source code-snippet for the app you are testing

Comment: You should make sure the element is in the page first, wait for element with a regular wait and after execute your script, so the issue would be that you are not waiting at all for the element to be present in the page.